# select * from table where id in (select group_concat(id) from table ) How to implement batch and new data using the group_concat function IN IN()?

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBaAE.png)SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id IN (select group_concat(id) from `user` GROUP BY sex) ;

I want the following result

```
UPDATE `user` SET average_age =  (SELECT AVG(score) FROM `score` WHERE id IN (select user_id from `score`))
```

SELECT AVG(score) FROM `user` WHERE id IN (1,2,3) ;
SELECT AVG(score) FROM `user` WHERE id IN (2,5) ;
......

How to implement batch and new data using the group_concat function IN IN()?

data :

```
  SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for user
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sex` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 12 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of user
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1, 'man', 21, 'Tom', 300);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (2, 'man', 23, 'Jerry', 350);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (3, 'woman', 18, 'Mary', 400);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (4, 'woman', 12, 'Lily', 450);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (5, 'woman', 16, 'Jasmine', 320);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (6, 'woman', 16, 'Jasmine', 420);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (7, 'woman', 18, 'Violet', 500);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (8, 'woman', 18, 'Violet', 580);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (9, 'woman', 20, 'Sophia', 520);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (10, 'man', 22, 'Charlotte', 450);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (11, 'man', 18, 'Jackson', 400);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `score`;
CREATE TABLE `score`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `average_score` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 12 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of score
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (1, '1,2,3', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (2, '2,5', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (3, '1,3,4,5', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (4, '2,3,6,8,11', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (5, '2,3,6', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (6, '2,3,4,5,6,7', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (7, '2,3,4,5,6,7', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (8, '3,4,5,9,10', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (9, '2', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (10, '3,5,8,9,10', NULL);
INSERT INTO `score` VALUES (11, '3,5,8,9,10', NULL);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: You've gone to a lot of trouble to correctly show us sample input data, but I don't see the output you actually want here.  Please show us the output you want, along with a description of it.

Comment: Could you clarify what are you trying to do. In the first query you seem to be trying to find users with different sexes and in the second one you are fetching minimum ages. What is it that you want to get as a result?

Comment: Maybe something like ```SELECT sex, MIN(age) FROM user GROUP BY sex;```?

Comment: The average_score is calculated by the relationship of the score table; the average_score is obtained from the score in the user table corresponding to the user_id in the score table; simply, the average_score in the score table is calculated by an update statement; the average_score is corresponding to the user_id. The average value obtained by the user in the user table;

Comment: I added a process picture to help understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'd like to correct a fundamental misconception indicated by the question title

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE name IN (select group_concat(name) from user GROUP BY sex)
```

(I've changed id to name to better illustrate my point)

This query is the conceptual equivalent of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE name IN (
  'John,Tim,Dave',
  'Sarah,Sally,Anne'
)
```

It's legal syntax but almost certainly NOT what you want. You don't write a query that uses IN by supplying a character string of values separated by commas like above, you supply IN with a list of values like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE name IN (
  'John','Tim','Dave',
  'Sarah','Sally','Anne'
)
```

This is a subtle but fundamentally huge difference, if you're not seeing it, leave me a comment

Your in queries should just be a query output list of the individual values you want to provide to IN, not a CSV string or list of CSV strings. Your query should thus be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE name IN (
  select name from othertable...
)
```

Now to your actual problem, you seem to want to update one table with summary data from another table:

```
UPDATE 
  `user` u 
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id, AVG(score) avgscore FROM `score` GROUP BY user_id)  a
  ON u.id = a.user_id
SET
  u.average_age = a.avgscore
```

We create a summary of scores by person, join it to the user table and update the user table

I would caution you however NOT to even do this because you're storing data hat can go out of sync. Instead of storing the avg in the user table just keep the data in the score table and re calc the average every time you need it:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  `user` u 
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT user_id, AVG(score) avgscore FROM `score` GROUP BY user_id)  a
  ON u.id = a.user_id
```

This could also be written as:

```
SELECT u.*, AVG(s.score) as avgscore
FROM
  `user` u 
  INNER JOIN
  `score` s
  ON u.id = s.user_id
GROUP BY 
  <list of columns in u>
```

I tend to avoid this patternnin favour of "group by first in a subquery, then join" because if you have two tables to join and summarise the third table can more easily wreck the stats of the second through causing values to repeat. In contrast grouping as a subquwery provides joins where there is only one row in a to match to one row in b, c etc. Oh, and writing the group by block out can be really onerous/boring